# Finding orphan mappings in Automapper

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper v9.0 in a ASP.net Core web api and after an extended time of adding, modifying and removing mappings in my profile classes I am starting to loose track of which mappings are actually used. In some cases the mapped classes still exist so the solution compiles without errors, but for one reason or another there might not be any need to map between these anymore. Is there a way to easily identify any orphan mappings so that I can remove them?